# Can I tell Mac OSX to lie to an installer about my OSX version?

Tags: install, driver

I have an old piece of video processing software that is no longer updated for the last couple of years.  The Macbook I have it installed on is running 10.11 Yosemeite.  My new Macbook Pro has 10.14 Mojave.  When I go to install it on this new computer it says that "Mac OS X 10.6 or Later Required."

The software includes drivers for the video capture card, so I certainly don't know for 100% that this software will even work with 10.14, but obviously it was just not in the installers listed of supported OS's yet, so it won't try.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to create a virtual environment or run in a compatibility mode or flat out lie to the installer about the version that I have installed to get it to try to install.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: That article doesn't answer this question. (1) It tells you how to modify truecrypt which doesn't match the app in the authors question (2) asks if there might be some other way of getting it to work which link doesn't address.

Comment: You can see if you can mode the installer as suggest in the link but you will have to figure out how.

Comment: You could try a virtual machine.  Check if the free version of parallels is still in the app store. You will need to get a copy of macos version that you need.  You can try the free Oracle VirtualMachine, but its hard to get to work.  VMware Fusion
With VMware Fusion, run the most demanding Mac and Windows applications side-by-side at maximum speeds without rebooting
http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/